# Почему $.get выполняется с каждым разом в два раза больше?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

есть код

```
$(document).change('.dateRange', function(event){
    
    event.preventDefault();
          
    let url = $(event.target).data('pjax-options');
    
    let selectId = $(event.target).data('select-id');
    
    
    var select = $('select[name="SearchCompanyForExpert[dateRange_' + selectId + ']"').val();
    
    url = url + '&selectval=' + select;
    
    
    $.get(url)
        .done(function(data) {
            $('.modal-body').html(data);
        });
        
    return false;
});
```

и вёрстка

```
<select class="form-control dateRange" name="SearchCompanyForExpert[dateRange_7]" data-pjax-options="/cabinet/tasks/expert-date?user_id=1798&amp;company_id=803" data-select-id="7">
<option>1</option>
и.т.д
</select>
<select class="form-control dateRange" name="SearchCompanyForExpert[dateRange_8]" data-pjax-options="/cabinet/tasks/expert-date?user_id=1798&amp;company_id=804" data-select-id="8">
<option>1</option>
и.т.д
</select>
..... и т.д
```

таких `select` на странице 20 штук , `name` у каждого уникальный `SearchCompanyForExpert[dateRange_'айдишник']`

При изменение какого-нибудь `select` , первый раз `$.get()` отправляет один запрос, второй раз `$.get()` отправляет 2 запроса, 3-й раз 4 запроса , 4-й раз 8 запросов , и.т.д в геометрической прогрессии. Почему это происходит? мне нужно чтобы одно изменение `select` -  один запрос.

если в самом начале сделать `console.log(event.target)` то выводится по одному селектору. именно который нужен, а `$.get()` шлёт выше описанным образом.

Как избавиться от подобного поведения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите код

```
$(document).change('.dateRange', function(event){
  ...
});
```

из того html-а, который возвращается `$.get(url)`-ом.

Comment: Точно! у меня в модальном окне этот код добавлялся каждый раз. Спасибо!

Comment: @Dmitriy Пожалуйста. Успехов.